# Haskell, replace every occurrence of the given word in the list

Tags: string, list, haskell, replace

I am stuck on how to change the given word in the list

```
change :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
change x y z
```

the function should work like giving word `x` and replace it with `y` in the list of `z`.

like `change 'a' 'c' "banana"` and the result would be `"bcncnc"`

How should I check the list recursively and change the every occurrence of the word?

My own attempt:

```
change st nd [] = []
change st nd (x:xs) = if st == x then nd : xs else x : xs
```

Comment: subst st nd [] = []
subst st nd (x:xs) =
  if st == x
  then nd : xs
  else x : xs

Comment: I`m just a beginner and not familiar with the recursive function in the Haskell, and I am not sure where I did wrong~

Comment: Your type signature should be `change :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just typed wrong on that part. It should be change :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current code, you are changing only the first element of this list (if it matches `st`), and appending the rest of the list `xs` unchanged.  You should apply the `change` function to the tail of the list.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I fixed that problem, thank you so much !